# Visualizar PDF libreria MPDF en UBUNTU

Tags: php, mysql, linux, mpdf

Tengo un sistema creado con PHP y MYSQL, instale la libreria MPDF utilizando COMPOSER, en mi PC WINDOWS todo funciona bien y logro visualizar y descargar el PDF sin problemas desde mi sistema pero cuando hago lo mismo en LINUX UBUNTO me muestra error **Esta pagina no funciona HTTP ERROR 500**.
En el servidor LINUX tengo otras librerias PHP como SPREADSHEET y PHPMAILER y funcionan sin problemas pero con MPDF no logro solucionarlo.

Espero por favor alguien me pueda orientar o indicar como lo soluciono o también si hay otra herramienta para generar PDF desde LInux que no sea difícil utilizarla....

Al revisar el log de errores de apache me muestra lo sigueinte:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Mpdf\MpdfException: Temporary files directory "/var/www/sistema.uicc.ua/sistema/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Config/../../tmp/mpdf" is not writable in /var/www/sistema.uicc.ua/sistema/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Cache.php:21\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/sistema.uicc.ua/sistema/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/ServiceFactory.php(61): Mpdf\Cache->__construct()\n#1 /var/www/sistema.uicc.ua/sistema/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Mpdf.php(1064): Mpdf\ServiceFactory->getServices()\n#2 /var/www/sistema.uicc.ua/sistema/pdf.php(5): Mpdf\Mpdf->__construct()\n#3 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/sistema.uicc.ua/sistema/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Cache.php on line 21, referer: https://sistema.uicc.uantof.cl/sistema/lista_formulario_8.php

Comment: ¿Qué te dice el log de errores? ¿Instalaste la librería en linux también, o solo pasaste la carpeta del proyecto al otro sistema?

Comment: Instale la libreria en linux, donde veo el log???

Comment: mira en la carpeta de apache, sino en la ruta /var/log/apache. Algo debería mostrarte.

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Mpdf\\MpdfException: Temporary files directory "/var/www/sistema.uicc.ua/sistema/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Config/../../tmp/mpdf" is not writable in /var/www/sistema.uicc.ua/sistema/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Cache.php:21\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/sistema.uicc.ua/sistema/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/ServiceFactory.php(61): Mpdf\\Cache->__construct()\n#1 /var/www/sistema.uicc.ua/sistema/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Mpdf.php(1064): Mpdf\\ServiceFactory->getServices()\n#2 /var/www/sistema.uicc.ua/sistema/pdf.php(5): Mpdf\\Mpdf->__construct()\n#3 {main}\n  thrown in

Comment: ese es el error cuando intento visualizar el pdf

Comment: Colócalo en tu pregunta. La puedes editar. En los comentarios es difícil leerlo.

Comment: Listo, lo agregue a la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todo apunta a que es un problema o de permisos dentro de tu carpeta personal, o de existencia de la carpeta donde vas a alojar tus pdfs. Tienes varias maneras de probar esto:

1. [Siguiendo estas especificaciones](https://mpdf.github.io/installation-setup/folders-for-temporary-files.html), puedes hacer:

   ```
   <?php

     // Require composer autoload
     require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

     $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['tempDir' => __DIR__ . '/custom/temp/dir/path']);
   ```
2. Cambiar los permisos en tu carpeta tmp. Prueba colocando permisos 755 o 777 (**SOLO SI ES PARA PRUEBAS**) y probar si el error persiste.

Los comandos para cambiar de permisos la carpeta es:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /custom/path/tmp //si deseas 755, solo colocas 755
```

Comment: En realidad los PDF no se alojaran en el sistema, son para descargar un reporte, realizan una consulta a la BD y se despliegan con la información consultada.

Comment: Y creo que sigues sin leer la documentación. El link que te pasé es bastante conciso. Te dice explíticamente que MPDF creerá un subdirectorio temporal para cachear los pdfs y este se limpiará luego de una hora. Así que no importa si es solo descargar. Esa librería necesita esa carpeta para funcionar.

Comment: Probé la primera opción y funciono, te lo agradezco mucho...

Comment: No es nada. Estamos para ayudarnos.

Comment: $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['tempDir' => __DIR__ . '/custom/temp/dir/path']);          Esa linea de codigo que agregaste, que hace especificamente???

Comment: Le dice a la clase Mpdf, dónde va a estar ubicado su carpeta temporal.

Comment: Gracias nuevamente por tu tiempo, estaba muy complicado con esto no sabia como solucionarlo.